# lldb using python output to generate arguments

Tags: python, gdb, lldb

in gdb there is a command like:

```
run $(python -c 'print "\x90"*90')
```

Where you use a pythons scripts output as your args. How do I do something like this in lldb?

Answer (score 2):

lldb doesn't have a way to mix python execution output into the command line like this.  Since lldb has always had a Python script interpreter ready to hand, it tends to rely on that for this sort of "script like" task.

The simplest example is just running a command you've made up in Python:

```
(lldb) script
Python Interactive Interpreter. To exit, type 'quit()', 'exit()' or Ctrl-D.
>>> lldb.debugger.HandleCommand("run {0}".format("\x90"*90))
```

You can also do this on one line:

```
(lldb) script lldb.debugger.HandleCommand("run {0}".format("\x90"*90))
```

which is handy if you do it a lot because you can make a command alias for this line, and invoke the alias.  And if you want to handle the errors or do further operations on the result, there's an equivalent `SBCommandInterpreter.HandleCommand` API that will return the error/result to you.

There are also more programmatic ways to do this particular job, for instance:

```
(lldb) script
Python Interactive Interpreter. To exit, type 'quit()', 'exit()' or Ctrl-D.
>>> launch_info = lldb.target.GetLaunchInfo()
>>> launch_info.SetArguments(["\x90"*90], True)
>>> error = lldb.SBError()
>>> lldb.target.Launch(launch_info, error)
```

if you have ambitions to do fancier stuff.

There's more info on the Python Scripting here:

https://lldb.llvm.org/use/python-reference.html

and on the SB API's here:

https://lldb.llvm.org/python_api.html

Comment: I am a little confused by "run {0}".format("\x90"*90). I can get the code to work without the "0" inside the "{}" what does the 0 do?

Comment: That's not an lldb thing, that's just the new-ish python string format syntax.  The 0 is a positional marker, since you can do things like `"{0} {1} {0}".format("outside", "inside")` to get: `'outside inside outside'`.  If you have only one substitution apparently you can leave off the 0, but that seems like an error-prone shortcut to me.  Not sure why the positional marker isn't working for you, however.